# OpenOCD FT2232H as SWD debugger with STM32L0 mcu

Tags: jtag, ftdi, swd, openocd

I would like to debug my MCU with OpenOCD. I run this command:

```
openocd -f interface/ftdi/minimodule-swd.cfg -f target/stm32l0.cfg
```

and then I get this prints from OpenOCD:

```
Open On-Chip Debugger 0.10.0+dev-00689-g6c2020eb-dirty (2019-02-09-17:42)
Licensed under GNU GPL v2
For bug reports, read
    http://openocd.org/doc/doxygen/bugs.html
Info : FTDI SWD mode enabled
swd
adapter speed: 300 kHz
adapter_nsrst_delay: 100
none separate
cortex_m reset_config sysresetreq
Info : Listening on port 6666 for tcl connections
Info : Listening on port 4444 for telnet connections
Info : clock speed 300 kHz
```

It seems that everything OK! but when I try to do telnet localhost 4444 I get

```
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Operating system?   Misconfigured firewall?   Exact telnet command line you used, and try something else?   On Linux or OSX try `netstat -nlp | grep 4444` to make sure it is actually doing what it says it is.   Also check OpenOCD site or repository for known issues.

Comment: Are you still pursuing this, or should we consider the issue abandoned and close it?